# What is the syntax error in this SQL/PHP Code?

Tags: php, mysql

Dreamweaver is reporting an error in the 3rd line of the following code:

```
if (isset($_POST['sitename']))
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO dllist (name, url, pr) VALUES ( "$_REQUEST['sitename'], $_REQUEST['siteurl'], $_REQUEST['pagerank']" )";
        $result = mysql_query($query) 
            or die("Query Failed".mysql_error());

        echo "<br />Website Has been added<br />";

    }
```

Also, when running the code in my browser the following error is reported

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_REQUEST' (T_VARIABLE)`

Can anybody tell me where the mistake is? I shall really be grateful.

Comment: At the very least, you need to quote your variables in your SQL statement.

Comment: You cannot concatenate strings to variables without a concatenation function.  In PHP, concatenation is dot (.)

Comment: SQL Injection invitation

Comment: @EricLeschinski In this particular case, a comma would do the trick too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commas (and the fact your missing the containers around your values (e.g. single quotes)), it should be:

```
        $query = "INSERT INTO dllist (name, url, pr) VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['sitename']."', '".$_REQUEST['siteurl']."', '".$_REQUEST['pagerank']."')";
```

Although this is still bad practice, and it has no SQL Injection protection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the string.  Change `VALUES ("` to `VALUES (" .`

Answer (score 1):

the values you put in insert query need to be single quoted individually like this:
 `$query = "INSERT INTO dllist (name, url, pr) VALUES ( '$_REQUEST['sitename']', '$_REQUEST['siteurl']', '$_REQUEST['pagerank']' )";`